# codename one using gui builder and css.

Tags: css, themes, codenameone

I am building a cn1 app and was so far using the "Theme" in the GUI Builder to change the look of containers and buttons. I now want to add a specific border to a container and I find it easier to accomplish the border through css, I found the instructions on how to do it and the code here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/rounded-corners-shadows-and-gradients-with-css.html . I added the .jar, made a css folder and add my theme.css file with the code. In my form's beforeshow method I change the uiid of a container to the uiid defined in my theme.css. However when I run the app the container takes on the default Container uiid, not the one defined in my .css. I feel like this is because I already have a theme defined in my gui builder with my uiids and now I am trying to change a container's uiid to a uiid defined in another theme. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have two themes and you want to use elements from both in the app. There are two valid scenarios, one where both of the themes are in the same res file and another where both of the themes are in a separate file.

If they are in the same res file do this:

```
theme = UIManager.initNamedTheme("/theme", "firstTheme");
UIManager.getInstance().addThemeProps(theme.getTheme("secondTheme"));
```

If they are in a separate files do this:

```
theme = UIManager.initNamedTheme("/theme", "firstTheme");
Resources otherTheme = Resources.openLayered(("/otherTheme");
UIManager.getInstance().addThemeProps(otherTheme.getTheme("secondTheme"));
```

This is discussed in the [Codename One Developer Guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/) under Theme Layering.

Comment: I have my theme.res which was is created by default. I then added the css-ant-task.jar and added a "css" folder in my root. In my css folder I added a "theme2.css" where I add the code for some uiids. This is a visual app so I'm using StateMachine and StateMachineBase. I tried adding this to my onstart: Resources otherTheme = Resources.openLayered("/theme2.css");
UIManager.getInstance().addThemeProps(otherTheme.getTheme("theme2")); But the app crashes with a nullpointer on the second line.

Comment: There is no CSS support, the css is translated to a separate res file so use `"/theme2"`. Notice I explicitly didn't specify a file extension. For the old GUI builder you need to place this code in the initTheme method. You don't need the first block with the `initNamedTheme` only a call to `super` and then do the other theme code.

Comment: That worked. Made a call to refreshTheme and it's working tit. Thanks shai

Comment: Hi guys, i have one question, i think my requirent is similar to the case of this question, i need to add some styling with css(already done and added css support), this generated an additional .res file in my project, the idea is to maintain the default theme in theme.res and just aply some styles on css. Tried Shai's advice in his answer in the part "if they are in separete files"(this in init method of my main class), and then in my Forms constructor added setUIID("style defined in second .res") but its not working, tried calling refreshTheme but just cant. It seems to ignore it

Comment: And just consider the first .res theme,any advice if im missing something? How can i debug this layering in themes?

Comment: I suggest filing a question with a proper description as it's hard for me to understand exactly what you did

Comment: Thanks for your help , it will not be neccesary ,found and error in my code, i was calling setThemeProps instead of addThemeProps